# How to map "$" character to "€" on French AZERTY keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'd like to have a direct access to "€" character by pressing the physical "$" key rather than having to do "Alt/Option + $".

I've been searching around and found this article:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

I try to use it, but "€" key code is not provided. Moreover, the layout is not for AZERTY keyboard. When I followed the provided example, instead of swapping "a" and "b", I ended up swapping "q" and "b".

Could anyone provide me with a solution please? Or the exact key code of "$" and "€" to use with hidutil?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a custom input source with the mapping you want with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).